# Cobb Douglas Indirect Utility/Expenditure continuity proofs

Tags: consumer-theory

How should I go about proving that the general Cobb Douglas indirect utility function and expenditure functions are continuous? There are many ways to prove continuity, but which would be the easiest? Are there any resources that already prove this? Thanks.

Comment: This is currently a low effort homework question and should be closed. There is not even an attempt of a formal statement of the question mathematically. What have you tried so far?